# Update class based on scope changes

Tags: angularjs, class, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im facing a little challenge here and I can't manage to find any proper solution. 
Im using a directive:

```
app.directive('colorcode', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('colorcode', function(data) {
                var status = attrs.colorcode.replace(/ /g, '_');
                element.addClass(status + "_status");
            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

to apply background color based on data status coming from a json call.

in the html is goes like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in entTask[0].tasks">
   <h5>{{key}}</h5>
   <div class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar" colorcode="{{value.status}}">
       <span>{{value.status}}</span>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

the directive adds a class based on the status when compiled

```
<div class="progress-bar status1" colorcode="{{value.status}}">
```

Now the problem I have is that when I update the ng-repeat scope, the directive does the work again but classes get added up like this.

```
<div class="progress-bar status1 status2 ..." colorcode="{{value.status}}">
```

I should watch for the old value and remove this class but I can't manage to make the $watch work properly... So Im quite stuck...

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: Seems like something using `ng-class` would work pretty well.

Comment: I though about this but status have spacing (eg: "ready to go")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue occurs because when you update the ng-repeat scope, angular does not re-create the html for items. So, I see two options.

1.Create a new task object from the old one then change the property of the new object and replace the old one by the new one. That makes angular create a new DOM object for the updated model object. Something like this:

```
$scope.change = function(index) {
  var copy = angular.copy($scope.entTask[0].tasks[index]);
  $scope.tasks[index].status = "new status";
  $scope.entTask[0].tasks[index] = copy;
};
```

2.Or you can stop using custom directive to change css and start using ng-class. Something like this:

```
// in the controller
$scope.convertToClassName = function (status) {
  // convert to a proper class name
  return convertedStatus;
};

// on the view
<div class="progress-bar" ng-class="convertToClassName(value.status)">
  <span>{{value.status}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use `ng-class` as @viktar said. That is what it is there for.

Comment: ng-class worked... I feel bad haha. However, I don't see how the first method would work as Im using a ng-repeat.

Comment: With ng-repeat angular builds DOM element for every object from the list. When you re-create an object in the list, angular removes DOM element that was associated with the old object and creates a new one. In this case your directive always adds a class to a fresh html fragment. In the case when you modify an inner object property, angular does not re-create anything as the old object is still used.

Comment: Yeah the ng-class solution there was something I was thinking, but didn't have time to test yesterday.  Good to know I was on the right track. So, the observable expression stuff must know how to parse `convertToClassName(value.status)` just fine?  That's awesome.